# Assert thrown by OpenCV checkVector() on otherwise valid vector<vector<Point3f>>

Tags: c++, opencv, assert, camera-calibration

Been chasing this bug all night, so please forgive any incoherence.

I'm attempting to use the OpenCV's `calibrateCamera()` to extract intrinsic and extrinsic parameters from a set of fifteen pictures whose object points and world points are given. From what I can tell from debugging, I'm grabbing valid points from the input files and placing them in a `vector<Point3f>`, which is itself placed into another `vector`.

I pass the whole shebang to `calibrateCamera()`,

```
double rms = calibrateCamera(worldPoints, pixelPoints, src.size(), intrinsic, distCoeffs, rvecs, tvecs);
```

which throws `Assertion failed (ni >= 0) in unknown function, file ...\calibration.cpp, line 3173`

Pulling up this file gives us

```
static void collectCalibrationData( InputArrayOfArrays objectPoints,
                                InputArrayOfArrays imagePoints1,
                                InputArrayOfArrays imagePoints2,
                                Mat& objPtMat, Mat& imgPtMat1, Mat* imgPtMat2,
                                Mat& npoints )
{
int nimages = (int)objectPoints.total();
int i, j = 0, ni = 0, total = 0;
CV_Assert(nimages > 0 && nimages == (int)imagePoints1.total() &&
    (!imgPtMat2 || nimages == (int)imagePoints2.total()));

for( i = 0; i < nimages; i++ )
{
    ni = objectPoints.getMat(i).checkVector(3, CV_32F);
    CV_Assert( ni >= 0 );
    total += ni;
}
...
```

So far as I know, a `Point3f` is of `CV_32F` depth, and I can see good data in the double vector just before calibrateCamera is called.

Any ideas what might be happening here? `calibrateCamera()` requires a `vector<vector<Point3f>>`, as said by http://aishack.in/tutorials/calibrating-undistorting-with-opencv-in-c-oh-yeah/ and the documentation; hopefully getMat(i) isn't failing due to that.

Could it possibly have been called on the `vector<vector<Point2f>>` of pixel points just after it? I have been over so many errors I am willing to believe anything.

**Edit:**
Consequently, `checkVector()`'s documentation was not really helpful

```
int cv::Mat::checkVector    (int elemChannels, int  depth = -1, bool RequireContinuous = true) const

returns N if the matrix is 1-channel (N x ptdim) or ptdim-channel (1 x N) or (N x 1); negative number otherwise
```

Comment: Maybe you could have a look at the calibration tutorial code for help:
http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/calib3d/camera_calibration/camera_calibration.html

Comment: @FSaccilotto , I had visited there and took their point about explicitly equalizing the number of world points and pixel points before the call. However, it does not address the error I am seeing. The only difference I could see in their handling of the world points was declaring `vector<vector<Point3f> > objectPoints(1);`, I omitted the `(1)`. I don't know if that alters it in some intangible fashion.

I didn't use their code explicitly because my world and pixel point correspondences were given, and it would have been more exterior code to debug.

Comment: Maybe you could also post your code, so we can have a look at it...
The last time I had a checkvector error, I also tested the output before calling the CV Function. 

`int ni = objectPoints.getMat(i).checkVector(3, CV_32F);`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is possibly in one of your InputArrayOfArrays arguments (in worldPoints precisely, if the assertion is thrown from the line pasted in your question). Mat:s should work just fine here.

I solved the same assertion error in my code by making all the 3 InputArrayOfArrays (or vector > and vector > in my case) same length vectors with fully populated entries. So my problem was in my architecture: my objectPoints vector was containing empty entries (even though the existing data was valid), and calibrate.cpp requires that no empty entries are present in any of the 3 InputArrayOfArrays. Btw I am using greyscale images for calibration so single channel data.

In calib3d source the most probable reason for throwing error is a null value if you have checked that data types match. You might try double-checking your valid input data:

1) count the # of valid calibration images from your chosen structure
`validCalibImages = (int)goodCalibrationImages.size()`

2) define worldPoints as `vector<vector<Point3f> > worldPoints`

3) IMPORTANT: resize to accommodate for data for each calibration entry
`worldPoints.resize(validCalibImages)`

4) populate with data e.g.

```
for(int k = 0; k < (int)goodCalibImages.size(); k++){
for(int i = 0; i < chessboardSize.height; i++){
for(int j = 0; j < chessboardSize.width; j++){
                objectPoints[k].push_back(Point3f(i*squareSize, j*squareSize, 0));
            }
        }
    }
```

'
Hope it helps!

Answer (score -1):

I agree with FSaccilotto - call checkVector and make sure you are passing a vector of size n of `Mat 1x1:{3 channel}` and not vector of `Mat 1 x n:{3 channel}` or worse `Mat 1 x n:{2 channel}` which is what MatOfPoint spits out.  That usually fixes 90% of assert failed issues.  Explicitly declare the Mat yourself.

The object pattern is somewhat strange in that the x y z coords are in the channels not in the Mat dimensions.